# The use of time markers with perfect infinitives

Tags: grammar

Tell me please if the following sentence is correct.

> He claims to have done his homework **yesterday**.

It is well known that it is grammatically incorrect to use time markers, such as **yesterday**, **last week** etcetera with the present perfect. But what about that sentence?

Comment: hmm but is that really the present perfect? What would the simple past version be? Would you say *he claims that he has done his homework yesterday*?

Comment: I would say "have done" is perfect in construction, but past tense in meaning. The sentence is no different from "he claims that he **did** his homework yesterday". The perfect construction is employed simply because "to" cannot be followed by a tensed (finite) verb.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the sentence. I'm more intrigued by the ambiguity of the past-tense version: *He **claimed** he did his homework yesterday.* Was it yesterday when he made the claim—or is his claim that he did it the previous day? The version in the question is actually *better* semantically, because it's unambiguous.